# solve this riddle based on foundational logics and proofs in descrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there was this question in the book "Discrete Mathematics" by kenneth rosen each inhabitant of a remote village always tells the truth or always lies .A villager will only give a "yes" or "no" response to a question a tourist asks. suppose you are a tourist visiting this area and come to a fork in the road. One branch leads to the ruins you want to visit ; the other branch leads deep into the jungle .A villager is standing at the fork in the road . What one question can you ask the villager to determine which branch to take?

Now the problem that i am facing with this question is that in the answer key the solution to this question is given as: if i were to ask you whether the right branch leads to the ruins would you answer yes.

But how would the response to this question help me determine which branch to take because if he is a liar he would respond negatively even if the right branch actually leads to the ruins , as he is a liar he has a tendency to give a wrong response even to that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with these kinds of problems is that the liars are perfect logicians. You aren't asking "does the right branch leads to ruins?", you're asking the villager what the villager would answer if you asked him a question.

The villager hears and understands the question as: "if you were to ask me whether the right branch leads to the ruins, would I answer yes?".

Case 1: right branch leads to ruin. Truth teller thinks "If you asked me whether the right branch leads to ruin then I'd answer 'yes'. You've asked me whether I'd answer yes, so I'll tell the truth". Villager answers 'yes (i.e. I would say yes, which is true)'.

Case 2: right branch leads to ruin. Liar teller thinks "If you asked me whether the right branch leads to ruin then I'd answer 'no'. You've asked me whether I'd answer yes, so I'll lie about that". Villager answers 'yes (i.e. I would say yes, which is a lie)'.

Case 3: right branch doesn't lead to ruin. Truth teller thinks "If you asked me whether the right branch leads to ruin then I'd answer 'no'. You've asked me whether I'd answer yes, so I'll tell the truth". Villager answers 'no (i.e. I would not say yes, which is true)'.

Case 4: right branch doesn't lead to ruin. Liar teller thinks "If you asked me whether the right branch leads to ruin then I'd answer 'yes'. You've asked me whether I'd answer yes, so I'll lie about that". Villager answers 'no (i.e. I would not say yes, which is a lie)'.

Getting the liar to talk about his hypothetical response make the liar lie twice.